# What is the formula for complex fourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am watching [this video on complex Fourier Series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aj6cYSRGv4w) where the instructor states  the formula as:
$$
f(x) = C_0 + \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}C_ne^{inx}
$$

where as the notes on the same topic by [Cambridge Uni](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~rwp/Maths/vid09/l7notes.pdf) state the formula as:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}C_ne^{inx}
$$

**Which is the right formula?**

Comment: Presumably in the first formula summation is taken over $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}.$  Then both of these formulas are equivalent.

Comment: The second since... it's nicer ! :-)

Comment: Don't you sense a redundancy in the first sum?  It's not that it's wrong, it's just...redundant.

Comment: @RonGordon I figured it out later that they put a condition in the second case that $n$ not equals 0 :)

Comment: Then what M Strochyk said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas say the same thing, since the first one should be written more precisely as
$$f(x) = C_0 + \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}} C_ne^{inx}$$
With complex Fourier series, there is little reason to separate the $0$th term from the rest of the sum. (One situation when it's done is when you want to write down $\int f(x)\,dx$.)

With [trigonometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_series) it's very common to separate the $0$th term: 
$$f(x)=A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_n\cos nx+B_n\sin nx)$$
because including $B_0\sin 0x$ feels silly.